# Какие аналоги C#/C++ Form Designer или “Web Inspector” для создания кастомных Editor Windows есть в Unity3d?

Tags: unity3d, utility

В `Unity3d`можно реализовать свое окно с нужным интерфейсом. 
Для добавления своих элементов управления на окно используются классы `EditorGUI` и `EditorGUILayout`.

Можно сделать что-то такое:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проблема состоит в том, что все делается на глаз и добавив что-то в код, приходится переключаться на окно редактора, ждать небольшой компиляции и смотреть результат своей разметки.

В веб разработке широко применяется `Web Inspector` (например нажав в F12  в хроме, вкладка Elements -> Styles), где можно в режиме реального времени добавить все нужные свойства элементу и посмотреть как это будет выглядеть.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Еще один более наглядный пример это `C# winFormApp/c++ MFC` и подобный приложения, у которых есть дизайнер формы, выбор элементов и возможность устанавливать различные свойства:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть ли подобные инструменты, утилиты, плагины для Юнити? Утилиты для инспекции кода, для инспекции и быстрого редактирования стилей, таких как position, margin, padding, background, width, height, color и т.д.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем, поискав, нашел только лишь недоработанный проект: [Editor window designer](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/editor-extension-editor-window-designer.337474/)

Автор начал усердно, но сейчас разработка ведется слабо и по разным причинам как [указывает автор](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/rel-open-source-editor-window-designer.375900/) исходники теперь лежат как  OpenSource на гитахабе: https://github.com/ahrenm/uAssist

Идея практически, которую я и искал.

Но и сейчас некоторые элементы управления можно добавить и немного стилизовать.
Вот Базовое окно:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот окно добавления и окно свойств добавленного элемента и отображение иерархии элементов формы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Возможно потом доберусь и буду развивать её.

Как до такого не додумались сами разработчики Юнити, мне не понятно. И как до сих пор до такого никто больше не додумался - тоже остается загадкой.